# Is FT232R/245R eeprom write-protectable?

Tags: ftdi

FT232R and FT245R have embedded EEPROM.

Does a known way to protect the content of this eeprom against re-writing exist?

(Any solutions, including unofficial and hacks, are welcome.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to write-protect the EEPROM on these parts. Even if you could, it'd be possible to effectively unprotect it by removing the chip and replacing it with an unprotected version.

Comment: I am worried about my own working process, not a third party action.